# How will people understand this “I am not in a/the good state"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Suppose I participate in a basketball game with my friends. I  do not play as well as usual. Can I explain to them:

> Sorry, I am not in the good state

Will the audience naturally take it to mean that now I am not in the good state in which I can play basketball well? Does it make sense to say that I can be in several possible states, in some of them I can play well in others play badly？

Comment: My game is not up to scratch

Comment: "I'm not playing up to snuff"

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you have not played for a long time or you don't play well anymore. Saying that you are not in a good state suggests that you might not be feeling well enough to play. That is not what you meant to say.

Comment: Or that you're in Arizona... zing!

Answer (score 1):

If talking about your ability to do something, you use **a** not **the**.

> I am not in a good state to play basketball today [I am not fit
>   enough] 
>   I am not in a good state to go to the meeting [My father just
>   died and I'm too upset to deal with people]

It can also be used as a positive:

> I've had lots of physio and now I'm in a good state to play.

'I am not in **the** state' implies you are not geographically located in a particular state, eg Florida